# Error: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'

Tags: python, error-handling, int

I am just starting with python and for this error. Would anyone know why and if I am saving my data as integers or how I can do this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gabriela Lammoglia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\open.py", line 34, in <module>
    latt2=mult*lattice
```

Code:

```
from csv import reader
from collections import defaultdict
from ast import literal_eval
from pprint import pprint

data = defaultdict(list)
with open('crystal.csv') as f:
    csv_reader = reader(f)

    current_header = None
    for line in csv_reader:

        # We found a header
        if len(line) == 1 and all(item.isalpha() or item.isspace() for item in line[0]):
            current_header = line[0]

        # Otherwise normal line with ints and floats
        else:
            data[current_header].append(list(map(literal_eval, line)))

pprint(data)

mult=data['multiplicty']
lattice=data['lattice parameters']
occup=data['occupancy']
sites=data['atom sites']

print(mult)
print(lattice)
print(occup)
print(sites)

import numpy as np
latt2=mult*lattice
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Both `mul` and `lattice` are `list` objects. So when you try to multiply two `list` objects, will result in `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'`. Try `[] * []` in your python interpreter :).

Comment: I did not know that I was getting a list when I extracted the data from the csv. I am trying to ideally multiply two vectors and get a vector as the output. Is there a way to convert the lists to vectors of integers?

Answer (score -2):

```
latt2=int(mult)*lattice
```

You need make mult value as integer. Now you try multiple string and list, it is bad idea.

Comment: I tried this and got this error:Type Error: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'. I am just getting started with Python is there a way to convert my lists to integers instead ?